# Find log session who accessed my folder via 'c$' on network

Tags: networking, security, shared-folders

I have audit set up via C: > security > advanced > auditing for all users on the network drive.

When in Computer Management > Shared Folders

I can only see live stream of current users accessing the computer.

But, how do I keep a history log of the event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the policy editor you have enabled under "Audit policy" the policy of
“Audit Object Access”, you should be getting the information in the Event Viewer.

Configuring auditing for a specific file or folder is by right-click,
Properties, Security tab, Advanced, Auditing tab, where you may specify
auditing for users and groups.

The event can be viewed using the Event Viewer, under
*Windows Logs > Security*.

The event you want is
[5140: A network share object was accessed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-5140),
which might look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Whats the difference between enabling `success` or `failed` for Audit Objects?

Comment: It's whether the access succeeded or failed.